# Wheels using ROS skid steer controller can't turn

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a four-wheeled robot with skid steer controller which works with teleop_twist_keyboard node. However the robot can only move forward or backward and I can't get it to turn left or right.

The skidsteer controller:

```
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
          <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
          <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>   
          <leftFrontJoint>left_front_wheel_joint</leftFrontJoint>
          <rightFrontJoint>right_front_wheel_joint</rightFrontJoint>
          <leftRearJoint>left_back_wheel_joint</leftRearJoint>
          <rightRearJoint>right_back_wheel_joint</rightRearJoint>
          <wheelSeparation>5</wheelSeparation>
          <wheelDiameter>0.6</wheelDiameter> 
          <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>  
          <torque>20</torque>
          <topicName>/cmd_vel</topicName>
          <broadcastTF>true</broadcastTF>
          <commandTopic>/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
          <odometryTopic>/odom</odometryTopic>
          <odometryFrame>/odom</odometryFrame>
          <covariance_x>0.0001</covariance_x>
          <covariance_y>0.0001</covariance_y>
          <covariance_yaw>0.0001</covariance_yaw>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309778/wheels-using-ros-skid-steer-controller-can%27t-turn/) by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2018-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why but adding contact stiffness, friction co-efficient and damping fixed it. Like:

```
<kp>1000000.0</kp> <!-- kp and kd for rubber -->
<kd>100.0</kd>
<mu1>1.0</mu1>
<mu2>1.0</mu2>
<maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
<minDepth>0.00</minDepth>
```

---

Originally posted by [the3kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38144/the3kr/) with karma: 91 on 2019-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omers](https://answers.ros.org/users/101802/omers/) on 2022-05-26**:
Can you post an example of how you added it please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI，I just got the same problem，and i fixed it with the following steps:
1.Upside down your model in gazebo with tools in toolsbar.
2.Control the wheels and see if they are turing in right direction. This step is to make sure that your plugin is working fine.
3.Then loose the model weight with the tag "mass".
4.If step 3 doesn't work fine, try to reduce the force param on wheel with tag "mu1 mu2 kd".
5.The final step is to increase the torque in controler plugin.

The following values can be used:
robot body: mass = 20
wheel : mu1=1 mu2=1 kd=100

---

Originally posted by [wfcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/55816/wfcola/) with karma: 11 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1